# Not able to alter column with Default function in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, default

Im trying to run this query to mask the contents in the column "audio" but keep getting the error message for wrong syntax

ALTER TABLE test
ALTER COLUMN audio varchar(10) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()');

Where am i going wrong here. Pls help

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support `MASKED WITH` syntax for [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-2017). That's a proprietary feature of Microsoft SQL Server.

Microsoft SQL Server is a different RDBMS product from MySQL. Both of these products have features and syntax not supported by the other.

In MySQL 5.7, the `DEFAULT` can be a constant scalar value, or NULL, or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Those are the only options (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html).

In MySQL 8.0, you can now use a constant expression for the default of a column (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html).

In both versions, you must use the `DEFAULT` keyword.

---

Re your comment:

> is there any other way, I can hide this column data for other users other than the root user

- You can define a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) that excludes columns you want to hide. The view can read the base table, but it does not select the `audio` column. Users can read the view, but do not grant access to the base table to all users.
- MySQL supports granting [column-level privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges), but I have never seen anyone use them, and I don't know if they really work.

Comment: Thank you very much Bill. is there any other way, I can hide this column data for other users other than the root user.